# Joda time: How do I find the number of milliseconds between 2 LocalTime objects?

Tags: java, jodatime

using Joda Time how do I find the number of milliseconds between 2 LocalTime objects?

LocalTime two = new LocalTime(2,0);

LocalTime six = new LocalTime(6,0)

So the number of milliseconds between 2am and 6am?

Thanks

Comment: `(this.hour - that.hour) * 60 * 60 * 1000` ? Doesn't Joda have some minus operation for time?

Comment: Yes, it would look something like this `six.minusMillis(two.getMillisOfDay()).getMillisOfDay()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
System.out.println(six.getMillisOfDay() - two.getMillisOfDay());
```